# Is the history of changes still available somehow?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

With Microsoft Word 2003, if someone has had Track Changes turned on, and then chooses 'Accept All Changes In Document', and then emails the document to someone, can they then see all the previous changes that were made?

In other words, is the history of changes still available somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Once the changes have been made, if you then save the document, the previous changes are no longer visible.

Comment: Is that no longer visible by looking at the document in Word, or no longer visible in anyway because they're no longer present in the file?

Comment: @Gilles Once the changes are confirmed and then the document is saved, it looses all meta data about the changes - so the document is the approved content only.

Comment: Thanks Wil, if you have a source I could quote that would be handy.